# How do I set text field for alert message in the alert dialog in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, alert, hybrid-mobile-app

I am getting a push notification using Firebase and showing it in alert box. Now I want to display the message i received in a text field so that user can edit the message.I also want to output the message in console.

```
pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
  if (notification.additionalData.foreground) {
    let youralert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Push notification',
      message: notification.message,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
           console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Okay',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Okay clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `inputs` property on the Alert interfacce, it works pretty much like the `buttons`. It's an array of objects and you have a input `value` property to set the desired value.

Since i don't know where you want to log you value and if it's the value that has come from the server or the edited value, i'll show both.

```
pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
  if (notification.additionalData.foreground) {
    console.log('push message', notification.message);
    let youralert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Push notification',
      inputs: [{
        placeholder: 'Your placeholder..',
        type: 'text',
        name: 'yourInputName, // Name to get it in your handler callback
        value: notification.message
      }],
      message: notification.message,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
           console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Okay',
          // you'll need to get the input data, so pass a parameter to the callback
          handler: (data) => {
            // here's the value user has edited in the input
            console.log('Edited message', data.yourInputName);
            console.log('Okay clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

Hope this helps